# Make fixed variables in the hashtable dynamic

Tags: powershell, dynamic

I have a hashtable with 3 fixed values, but now I want the script to automatically recognize how many values ​​I have and then dynamically create the records.

```
$ComuterSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem  
$cpu = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average).Average
$platte = (Get-PhysicalDisk)
$ssds = (Get-PhysicalDisk | ? model -Match 'ssd') 
$disksum = (Get-PhysicalDisk).Count

$ssdsum = 0
foreach($platte in $ssds) {
    $ssdsum++
}

$disksum = (Get-PhysicalDisk).Count
$hddsum = $disksum - $ssdsum

#RAM
$ram_freephysical = 0
$ram_totalvisible = 0
$ram_freephysical = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *freePhysical* | Out-String
$ram_totalvisible = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *totalvisiblememory* | Out-String
$ram_freephysical = $ram_freephysical -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$ram_totalvisible = $ram_totalvisible  -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$ram = $ram_totalvisible - $ram_freephysical
$ram = [Math]::Round($ram / $ram_totalvisible * 10000) / 100

#disk
$storage = foreach ($Computer in $ComuterSystem) {
    $LogicalDisk = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "drivetype=3" -ComputerName $ComuterSystem.Name

    $diskHash = @{}
    foreach ($disk in ($LogicalDisk.Where({$_.DeviceID}))) {
        $diskHash.Add($disk.DeviceID, $disk.Size)
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Computer.Name
        Model = $Computer.Model
        Manufacturer = $Computer.Manufacturer
        # Easiest is to simply store all data:
        LogicalDisk = $LogicalDisk
        # Or store the hashtable with your key value pair
        Disks = $diskHash
        # Or store a selection of what you need
        Selection = $LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, VolumeName, Size, FreeSpace
    }
}

#collector
$stats = [ordered]@{
    $computer.Name = @{
        "Utilization" = @{
            CPUusage = $cpu
            RAMusage = $ram
        }
        "" = @{
            SSDsum = $ssdsum
            HDDsum = $hddsum
            Disksum = $disksum
        }
    }
    "Storage" = @{
        Festplatte1 = $storage.Selection[0]
        Festplatte2 = $storage.Selection[1]
        Festplatte3 = $storage.Selection[2]
    }
}

#convertor
$stats | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path C:\Temp\yyy.json
```

The ouput is this:

```
{
    "W10-NICO": {
        "Utilization": {
            "CPUusage": 11,
            "RAMusage": 73.46
        },
        "": {
            "Disksum": 3,
            "SSDsum": 2,
            "HDDsum": 1
        }
    },
    "Storage": {
        "Disk1": {
            "DeviceID": "C:",
            "VolumeName": "System",
            "Size": 63020462080,
            "FreeSpace": 35570368512
        },
        "Disk2": {
            "DeviceID": "G:",
            "VolumeName": "SSD",
            "Size": 63020462080,
            "FreeSpace": 62914928640
        },
        "Disk3": {
            "DeviceID": "F:",
            "VolumeName": "Daten",
            "Size": 499529019392,
            "FreeSpace": 481141452800
        }
    }
}
```

But if I have only 2 instead of 3 hard drives, I have a problem and I have no idea how to do it.

Maybe someone can help me and add the dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to build the hashtable with the disk information:

```
$disks = [ordered]@{}
for ($i=1; $i -le $storage.Selection.Count; $i++) {
    $disks["Disk${i}"] = $storage.Selection[$i-1]
}
```

Then put that hashtable into your `$stats` hashtable:

```
$stats = [ordered]@{
    $computer.Name = @{
        "Utilization" = @{
            CPUusage = $cpu
            RAMusage = $ram
        }
        "" = @{
            SSDsum = $ssdsum
            HDDsum = $hddsum
            Disksum = $disksum
        }
    }
    "Storage" = $disks
}
```

Comment: Now I get the disk C (Disk 1 in the PC) not at all, however, the disk F (Disk 2 in the PC) as Disk 1 in the script... this makes no sense

Comment: @Nicolai My mistake. There was an off-by-one in my sample code. `$storage.Selection[$i]` should have been `$storage.Selection[$i-1]`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially do the same as you have already done in this bit:

```
$diskHash = @{}
foreach ($disk in ($LogicalDisk.Where({$_.DeviceID}))) {
        $diskHash.Add($disk.DeviceID, $disk.Size)
}
```

*Aside: Note that $LogicalDisk does not have a .Where method.*

Use `$LogicalDisk | ? {$null -ne $_.DeviceId}` instead.

It may require that you rewrite the script a litte. Instead of writing your collector part as a declared ordered hashtable, write a few lines which creates the hashtable as you create the values, or even better, write a function for each part of the script and tie it together in a small script in the end.

Here is an example of how you might structure one of the functions:

```
function Get-RamStat {
    param (
        $ComputerName = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
    )
    $OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    @{
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        FreePhysicalMemory = $OS.FreePhysicalMemory
        TotalVisibleMemorySize = $OS.TotalVisibleMemorySize
        Ram = math::round(($os.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $os.FreePhysicalMemory)/$os.TotalVisibleMemorySize * 10000) / 100
    } | Write-Output
}
```

It's still the same data, but now you can order the collection of the data first and the formatting  of the data last. And you can scale up by running the function in a loop.

Excuse the long-winded way of answering. I am quite new to writing SO-answers.
I hope it helps :)